# talend rest is there a request log i can see what headers/ vars were sent

Tags: rest, talend

I have an api i am sending via talend using a tRest component

the following curl command works fine

```
curl -v -D - -H 'Authorization: Token token="{private api key]"' -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X GET -d ' {"id":"135329"}' "https://app.mobilecause.com/api/v2/reports/results.json?"
```

however the setup in talend is giving me a result that is saying the report # is not found, leading me to believe something is off in the headers
[image]

ive tried a regular run, a trace debug run, but I can see no place where it logs the actual request that was sent with the headers ive described so i can troubleshoot why the cUrl request works and the tRest component does not

Comment: Have you tried to use tRestClient component ? It has a "LOG message" option in advanced settings.

Comment: i thought that restclient was for ESB package using Apache CXF technology, while tRest was for internet rest technology

Comment: I think 'id' value should be in URL, like: /results.json?id=135329